# How to set Gmail as default mail client in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, gmail, ubuntu-11.04

How do I set Gmail as the default mail client in Ubuntu 11.04?

[gnome-gmail](http://gnome-gmail.sourceforge.net/) does not work for me. It works in 10.04, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem with the latest GNOME. See the PPA link at http://gnome-gmail.sourceforge.net/, or fix your desktop file a la http://gnome-gmail.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=gnome-gmail/gnome-gmail;a=blob;f=gnome-gmail.desktop.in;h=6f89d7e90b3fb8e3603990d188825bc9c2949495;hb=HEAD (add x-scheme-handler/mailto; to MimeType).

Comment: yes, link fromppa gnome-gmail-1.7.2-1ubuntu3_all.deb works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find a browser-specific solution:

If you're using chrome, you might try this chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pgphcomnlaojlmmcjmiddhdapjpbgeoc#

If you're using Firefox, this site appears to have some instructions on how to do it: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-ways-set-gmail-default-email-default-browser/

Comment: I want to open Gmail even I click email link in my IMclient or Send->e-mail in Nautilus. So, your answer is not for me.